# start cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android

I have looked everywhere and have not found an answer that works. the issue i am having is i am making a music player and the media player.start won't work. here is the menu.java:

```
package com.hunter.pixalia;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class Menu extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

            //buttons
    Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent start = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorldSelect.class);
            startActivity(start);
        }
    });
      final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.summertime_sadness);


              Button b = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
              b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.start; //<-- issue
                }
            });

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, (android.view.Menu) menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Menu" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Start" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:src="@drawable/pixalia" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Music" />
```

i have tried cleaning, there is no android.R; import and i have done control+shift+o. nothing works and i don't know the problem. I also tried to use

```
import com.pixalia.menu.R;
```

nothing will work

Comment: consider using  more descriptive names than `button1`, `button2`, `imageView1`, and `b`. Picking more descriptive id and variable names will make your code easier to understand.

Comment: 'Nothing works', 'nothing will work' etc are not acceptable as problem descriptions. The actual issue here is *compilation errors.* You need to say so, and quote the text and the line they occur on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it seems to be just a typo. If you see the documentation of [start](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#start%28%29), it seems to be a function. I think functions should be defined as `mp.start();` not `mp.start;`.

Comment: i did this and it got rid of the error but it wont run. in the console it says:

Comment: Post the error in the question.

Comment: woops:Installation failed due to invalid URI!
 Please check logcat output for more details.
 Launch canceled!

Comment: all the logcat says is compiler shutdown in progress - disgarding request

Comment: nvm i restarted eclipse and it works